# Escaping dollar sign in a wmi query filter

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to query a service named AOS60$01

`get-service 'AOS60$01'` works fine but when I use:

`get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "Name='AOS60$01'"` it does not return anything. I assume it thinks $01 is a variable and replaces it with an empty string that's why it is not working. Tried escaping the dollar sign with a backslash but it did not work. How do I escape it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with a backtick ` :

```
get-wmiobject win32_service -filter "Name='AOS60`$01'"
```

Comment: Alternatively switch single and double quotes: `get-wmiobject win32_service -filter 'Name="AOS60$01"'`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use double quotes "$test" you get the value of the variable. When you use single quotes '$test' you get it as-is.

As you are using single quotes inside the string, either of the two ways of doing it are appropriate:

```
... -filter "Name='AOS60`$01'"
```

This uses a backtick ` to escape it.

Alternatively you can use single quotes and escape them instead:

```
... -filter 'Name=''AOS60$01'''
```

To escape a single quote, put another single quote in front of it.